# jQuery UI dialog with iFrame position with multiple dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Working with jQuery modal dialog.

I have a link , clicking on it i have to load a page inside a modal.This page has some page specific javascript and also have the same name, id used in the parent page for many controls.

Decided to load the page in modal with iFrame to avoid id conflicts.

**Parent.html**

```
<h3>
 Modal Inside Modal Sample</h3>

 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="lnkPopup">Open Main Modal</a>
    <br />
    <input id="txt-first-name" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
    <br />
    <input id="txt-last-name" name="LastName" type="text" value="" />
```

Here is javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#lnkPopup').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModalPopup();
            });
        });

        var myModalDialog;

        function openModalPopup() {
            myModalDialog = null;


            var pageUrl = 'popup.html';
            var dialogFrame = $('<iframe src="' + pageUrl + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');

            myModalDialog = dialogFrame.dialog({
                modal: true,

                resizable: false,

                draggable: false,

                autoOpen: true,

                position: "fixed",

                closeOnEscape: true,

                height: 500,

                width: 764,

                open: function () {
                    var scrollPosition = [self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft, self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop];
                    var html = jQuery('html'); // it would make more sense to apply this to body, but IE7 won't have that       
                    html.data('scroll-position', scrollPosition);
                    html.data('previous-overflow', html.css('overflow'));
                    html.css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);
                    dialogFrame.css('width', '700px');
                    dialogFrame.css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
                },
                close: function () {
                    var html = jQuery('html');
                    var scrollPosition = html.data('scroll-position');
                    html.css('overflow', html.data('previous-overflow'));
                    window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);
                    $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();

                }
            }).dialog('open');

            return false;
        }
```

**Note:** The most important thing is the popup page also has the link and opens itself as a modal in when we click. opening a modal inside modal and both modal url is same.

**POPUP(popup.html) and Parent(parent.html) Page Both contains same HTML/JS content**

The problem is alignment issues. it is not positioning well. I tried to fiddle my problem, but i have no idea about creating two html file and linking them. Tried version of **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/muralitcs/Lq9Je/2/)**

[image]

Please help me to solve this modal alignment issue. Each modal should position exactly on top of other modal from which we are opening.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a function in the main window for opening these dialogs.
Then every links in your dialogs should call that function (from main window)
with calling `window.parent.your_function_name()`.

Comment: No. I never call from parent window. I call from current window/popup opened. Your solution will not work for me